# Multiple filters during backpropagation in convolutional neural network

Tags: conv-neural-network, backpropagation

Let's say we have an Input **10x10x3** (WxHxD) and **5** filters **3x3x3**. Convolution between Input and filters will be **8x8x5**.

During backpropagation we will get error with the same size **8x8x5**. While calculating **dE/dF** how do I perform convolution when depth between filters and error do not match. The same thing goes to **dE/dX**.

I understand that I need to perform 'FULL' convolution while calculating **dE/dF** but that's just impossible without the same depth.

Answer (score 1):

In the forward pass, you can see that each of the five filters is responsible only for one of the depth channels of the output. I think that also applies when calculating dE/dF: doing 'normal' convolution between input and each channel of the output error will give you dE/dF for one filter. By iterating over all output channels, you get dE/dF for all filters.